# File upload freezes in all the applications in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 while it worked well until I manually ran `sudo apt upgrade -y --allow-downgrade` some day. (I forgot about the upgrade details though). After that I found:

1. My Prt Sc key no longer works
2. All the file uploads will cause the application to freeze, it happens on Chrome, Brave Browser and Slack and some other applications.

What should I do to fix this problem? Is this something related with gnome-shell? Thank you very much!

Comment: sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
this solve the problem for me !
thanks to @Uharov Andrii

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I think I found the solution.

Try changing `chrome://flags/#ozone-platform-hint` to "Wayland" and relaunching Chrome

EDIT:

otherwise, try launching Chrome from the CLI like that

`google-chrome --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland`

Comment: Thank you sir! But mime seems to be a global issue not only happens with Chrome. Anyway I just switched to another desktop environment instead of GNOME so it solved my problem. But thank you very much

Comment: that make my chrome infinite crashing on startup

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer in this bug report:
[link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970148)

All you need is to install this package:

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

It has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those that experience the problem still in Chrome and found

This here solved the issue for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1453108/22152