# Google Chrome freeze uploading a file

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

My Google Chrome app freezes when I select a file from an HTML input tag of type "file".

This is a very simple code to reproduce the error:

https://jsfiddle.net/aL4e6n29/

After I select any file, and even if I click on cancel, the Chrome window becomes unresponsive. I cannot click on anything, change the tab or close the windows.

I tried to disable "Use hardware acceleration when available", but it doesn't solve the problem.

System:

- Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- HP HP ProBook 450 G8 Notebook PC*
- Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Check the bug report here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970148

As proposed by Olivier Tilloy in the bug report, the command

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

solved my problem.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on Xorg with Nvidia card.

Comment: Thanks! it works

Comment: I've tried this and didn't work here. Ubuntu 22.04 on Xorg as well. The error only occurs when I'm using Brave, Firefox and Chrome are fine.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me also

Comment: I already had `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` installed and still faced this problem. Disabling hardware acceleration on Chrome fixed it for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me and a also had hardware acceleration already disabled.

Comment: fixed after reboot

Comment: Can confirm Lin Sun's suggestion worked for me, thanks.

Comment: I had this bug on file chooser and opening print dialog. This solution fixed both of them.

Comment: This bug has been causing me grief for so long - annoyed that it took me this long to look it up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: worked for me only after reboot

Comment: worked after restarting chrome

Comment: This works for me but after I reboot the problem comes back!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, too!

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration on my Brave browser did the trick for me. The above solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Wow this is perfect, thanks a lot man !
PS : I am using the nvidia-driver-530

Answer (score 12):

As I reported [here in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970148/comments/37), and many user confirmed, the solution proposed do not always work.
Probably this error can be caused by different setups and configurations.

In particular installing `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` or disabling hardware acceleration didn't worked for me.

For those cases, I found a solution [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1315684#c17):

Basically I used `dconf-editor` to turn to `false` `org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedkback-sounds` and this solved the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1, this worked instantly, whereas the xdg-desktop-portal-gnome was already installed and turning hw acceleration of is a no-go. Thanks!

Comment: This is one of the true "WTF" linux moments, that worked for me as well for 23.04. Worth to notice that I didn't had the `input-feedkback-sounds` conf in place, so writing the command created it and set it to false. I guess that is true by default. `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedback-sounds false` works as well without installing an extra unneccessary tool

Answer (score 5):

dconf-editor solved this problem for me after turning "org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedkback-sounds" to "false".

You can install the dconf-editor by using the following command:

`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`and then type `dconf-editor` in the terminal a pop-up window will open for dconf-editor and the nyou can navigate to the appropriate path and the n turn off the required setting then the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank for the clear explaination. it was the good solution for me

Comment: `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedback-sounds false` works as well without installing an extra unneccessary tool

Comment: worked for me too

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the two suggestions (xdg-desktop-portal-gnome nor disable hardware acceleration) quite works for me.  What I find is that I simply have to toggle disable hardware acceleration on and off at some point in my session. If I don't do that, the reported issue appears. The window completely freezes after a file upload dialog.

Version 104.0.5112.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I do not experience this issue if I use google-chrome-beta on the same platform.

I hope that proves helpful to someone.

Comment: I find if I wait it out, like 5 minutes, it unfreezes, so I am trying to see who is sucking down the CPU all that time, if top is updating.  I just got multiple freezes using gnucash showing a report, plus lots of dialog popups not responding kill or wait.  Chrome with acceleration disabled (weird that there is such a control!) was running but all 4 windows minimized, also minimized libreoffice first screen, boinc manager, pulseaudio, disks, nautilus, gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling hardware acceleration and restarting Google Chrome (v104) solved it for me. I wish there would be a better solution.

Comment: Where you do disable hardware acceleration?

Comment: Click on the three dots on the right of your browser window, select "Settings" > "System" and you should see a Checkbox that you can disable: "Use hardware acceleration if possible".
A Chrome-restart is required.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1970047/comments/9

Running
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound input-feedback-sounds false`
seems to be fixing the issue. It worked for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Even with org.gnome.desktop.sound input-feedback-sounds = false, Chrome hangs (for me) when it calls the native file chooser.

This page gave me an idea:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=716892

which refers to the GTK_MODULES env variable.  I am using Linux MATE, and its system-wide GTK_MODULES var = canberra-gtk-module.  So I edited the /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome shell script (as root) and added this line:

unset GTK_MODULES

near the top.  Now run Chrome normally and the hang after file chooser problem is gone.

Based on what I read, canberra-gtk-module connects GTK apps like Chrome to event sounds.  Apparently the file chooser can call an event sound which will or  may work if GTK_MODULES var = canberra-gtk-module.  Unsetting that env. var apparently should mean no event sounds when using Chrome.  I never heard such sounds before with the file chooser, but there are still event sounds with when adjusting volume, and video sound still works fine.  So I don't really understand why the freeze happens; I'm guessing it's not a Chrome problem.

The above is not a great solution though, since that shell script can get replaced by an update.

Note:  I didn't try installing xdg-desktop-portal-gnome because MATE doesn't use Gnome-shell and it would have installed a bunch of packages I didn't want in MATE.

Answer (score 0):

Since all apps ,settings were already applied as discussed above, none worked. Until I noticed I didn't switched on my second monitor (hdmi/displayport) which also supplies the audio. Switching on the second monitor solved the problem instantly. (Both chrome and firefox)
Hope I can help someone with this as it took me 1.5h to solve it.