# Google Chrome freezes with file upload or download in Ubuntu Jammy 22.04

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

Chrome version: 100.0.4896.127

I am not using Wayland (because that breaks Zoom).

Firefox does not have this problem, but "Show in folder" from the list of downloads does nothing.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail using more words, what were you trying to do? What file? Which site? etc.

Comment: Solved here! [Google Chrome freeze uploading a file](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404974/617739)

Comment: This is the fix that worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404550/google-chrome-freeze-uploading-a-file