# Chrome and Firefox freezes when I upload files / interact with nautilus (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: nautilus, google-chrome

I have already disabled wayland, but this not helps.

Issue is, if i select a file to upload in a webform or do similar things, chrome freezes. I noticed also that when i download a file the small folder icon in the chrome download tab, that opens the download directory do not works. I suppose there is some errors while the web browser interact with the local files. .

Any help is appreciated, i was happy to have 22.04 but now i miss 20.04 lts. .

Answer (score 12):

I solved with this command guys:

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

Then restart your computer.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970148

Comment: Solved without restarting.

Comment: Life saving answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with https://askubuntu.com/a/1406325 but that didn't work. The issue was mainly with Hardware acceleration.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970148/comments/32

Use this link as reference, to disable the hardware acceleration and restart your browser.

Answer (score 0):

This one solved the problem for me without having to sacrifice hardware acceleration: https://askubuntu.com/a/1453108/22152